# Limit Exceed for Auto Number Field

Tags: apex, custom-field, fields

i have an AutoNumber field which created in format IN -{0000}, this is my format.here i can insert upto 10k recoeds{0000}.what will happend if limit exceed more than 10k..?

Comment: I believe this question is different than the above possible duplicate. The possible duplicate is about how long the autonumber can be not what happens after the set format is exceeded which I believe is an important distinction between the questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer the help document- [What happens when my auto-number field reaches a number that exceeds the specified digits?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214175&language=en_US&type=1).

Adding details here from documentation:

> **Question**: If I specify my Auto-Number Format as A-{0000}, what number
>   will be assigned to the record following A-9999?
>
> **Answer**: The number portion of the Auto-Number format will expand an
>   extra digit(s) to accommodate for large numbers once the sequence has
>   reached the capacity of the specified digits.  For this example, the
>   next record will be assigned A-10000.  Then A-10001, A-10002, etc.

Comment: Even i have checked this thanks for ur Responce @Rahul Sharma.